# Siunitx, saving variables and calculation with FP

Tags: siunitx

I am trying to store variables with some info about them, perform calculations on the variable number and display it correctly with siunitx. This works great when only saving numerals as the variable, but trying to save the variable as the output of fpeval produces errors. It might seem as if it is not really storing the output of fpeval, but the formula itself, although I am not quite sure. In the code below, I have commented out the line producing the error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\usepackage[per-mode=fraction]{siunitx} % also loads xparse and expl3
\sisetup
  {
    exponent-to-prefix = true        ,
    round-mode         = figures     ,
    round-precision    = 3           ,
    scientific-notation = engineering,
  }


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\varSet}{mmmm}
 {
  \prop_gclear_new:c { g_giacomo_var_#1_prop }
  \prop_gput:cnn { g_giacomo_var_#1_prop } { value } { #2 }
  \prop_gput:cnn { g_giacomo_var_#1_prop } { unit } { #3 }
  \prop_gput:cnn { g_giacomo_var_#1_prop } { name } { #4 }
 }

 \NewDocumentCommand{\varChange}{mm}
 {
  \prop_gput:cnn { g_giacomo_var_#2_prop } { value } { #1}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\varPrint}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
      \exp_args:Nnx \SI { \__giacomo_get:nn { #2 } { value } }
        { \__giacomo_get:nn { #2 } { unit } }
   }
   {
    \__giacomo_get:nn { #2 } { name }
   }
 }



% syntactic sugar
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\varGet}{m}
 {
  \__giacomo_get:nn { #1 } { value }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__giacomo_get:nn #1 #2
 {
  \prop_item:cn { g_giacomo_var_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }
\cs_set_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff


\varSet{Area}{1}{\metre\squared}{A_{rmin}}
\varSet{Width}{200}{\metre}{W_{sq}}
\varSet{Length}{10}{\metre}{L_{sq}}

\begin{document}
Input Length = $\varPrint*{Length}$\\
Input Width = $\varPrint*{Width}$\\
Calculated area: \fpeval{\varGet{Width}*\varGet{Length}}\\

%\varSet{Area}{\fpeval{\varGet{Width}*\varGet{Length}}}{\metre\squared}{A_{rmin}}
Saved Area: $\varPrint*{Area}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to perform operations in the “value” argument of `\varSet`, you need to use `\prop_gput:cnx` in the corresponding line; this will just do a useless expansion also when the value is explicit, but it's nothing to worry about.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\varSet}{mmmm}
 {
  \prop_gclear_new:c { g_giacomo_var_#1_prop }
  \prop_gput:cnx { g_giacomo_var_#1_prop } { value } { #2 }
  \prop_gput:cnn { g_giacomo_var_#1_prop } { unit } { #3 }
  \prop_gput:cnn { g_giacomo_var_#1_prop } { name } { #4 }
 }
```

In this way the third argument is fully expanded (which is possible with `l3fp` compliant syntax) before the value is stored in the property list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\usepackage[per-mode=fraction]{siunitx} % also loads xparse and expl3
\sisetup
  {
    exponent-to-prefix = true        ,
    round-mode         = figures     ,
    round-precision    = 3           ,
    scientific-notation = engineering,
  }


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\varSet}{mmmm}
 {
  \prop_gclear_new:c { g_giacomo_var_#1_prop }
  \prop_gput:cnx { g_giacomo_var_#1_prop } { value } { #2 }
  \prop_gput:cnn { g_giacomo_var_#1_prop } { unit } { #3 }
  \prop_gput:cnn { g_giacomo_var_#1_prop } { name } { #4 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\varChange}{mm}
 {
  \prop_gput:cnn { g_giacomo_var_#2_prop } { value } { #1}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\varPrint}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \exp_args:Nnx \SI { \__giacomo_get:nn { #2 } { value } }
        { \__giacomo_get:nn { #2 } { unit } }
   }
   {
    \__giacomo_get:nn { #2 } { name }
   }
 }



% syntactic sugar
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\varGet}{m}
 {
  \__giacomo_get:nn { #1 } { value }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__giacomo_get:nn #1 #2
 {
  \prop_item:cn { g_giacomo_var_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }
\cs_set_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff


\varSet{Area}{1}{\metre\squared}{A_{rmin}}
\varSet{Width}{200}{\metre}{W_{sq}}
\varSet{Length}{10}{\metre}{L_{sq}}

\begin{document}

Input Length = $\varPrint*{Length}$

Input Width = $\varPrint*{Width}$

Calculated area: \fpeval{\varGet{Width}*\varGet{Length}}

\varSet{Area}{\fpeval{\varGet{Width}*\varGet{Length}}}{\metre\squared}{A_{rmin}}
Saved Area: $\varPrint*{Area}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works flawlessly. Great explanation too, really helpful.